# html5, how to style Figure differently for different case?

Tags: css, html

I want to display the figcaption on bottom of figure when it is on single page, and display it side by side with figure when on a list page. So, I added "list" or "single" class to the figure tag. Then, in css file I use this 2 code to style them differently:

```
figure .list{....}
figure .single{...}
```

The above css does not have any effects on the figure display. Only figcaption react to the `.class figcaption` code. How can I correct it?

Comment: This is a basic of Cascading Style Sheets. Shame on you.

Comment: @iegik It's not because something is basic to you, it's basic to everyone else. This is a Q&A site for everybody, no matter what knowledge he or she has of the topic, so you should not criticise them on it.

Comment: Ok, but this Q&A site recommends do little bit research before asking. I think abbreviation "CSS" itself discribes, that rule ```.list figcaption``` will apply rules by cascade. Btw, author already have the answer in question itself. :)

Comment: the figure class does make sense to the figcaption, but I also want to style the figure itself. The problem is the figure itself does not react to the css class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to style the figcaptions. To do so, you need to target them. Also when adding a class to an element, the class should be written connected to the element, like so:

```
figure.list > figcaption { }
figure.single > figcaption { }
```

This only works when `figcaption` is a direct child of the figure (hence `>`). If it is not, you can use this:

```
figure.list figcaption { }
figure.single figcaption { }
```

---

If you wish to target elements with a class in CSS, write the class connected to the element with a dot. Like so:

```
figure.list { }
```

It is possible that this CSS is overwritten by **a)** a style added by another file (e.g. JS or PHP files) or an inline style **b)** a style that is written after the first style **c)** a style that targets the same element but that is defined more thoroughly/specifically **d)** [`!important`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/).

```
body figure.list {float: left;}
figure.list {float: none;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/N7gPW/). Even though one would expect the value in the second line to overwrite the previous line, **this will not happen** because the first line is more specific than the last.

If you cannot seem to find why your styles are not displaying correctly, try using the *developer tools* of your browser (F12). Chrome's tools are very good, but I don't really like Firefox's. You can, however, use the [Firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I also need to style the figure-- add a question mark as content before one figure, while the other figure without any content before. But the result is 2 figures get the question mark

Comment: @Jenny I'm sorry, but I don't understand at all what you are trying to say.

Comment: for example, figure.list should display as block while figure.single should display as float:left to allow other content wrapping around.

Comment: Got it! I found in firebug that the figure was styled by another plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your space before the dot:

```
figure.list{....}
figure.single{...}
```